# Does the location of placing my <script> in html matter? Why does this code only work in one example? (code attached)

Tags: javascript, html

This doesn't work:

```
  <h2>Dinosaurs are cool.</h2>

  <script>
  document.querySelector('.change-text').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('h2').innerText = 'I AM A DINOSAUR!!!';
  }); </script>

  <button class='change-text'>Change Text</button>
```

But this does:

```
  <h2>Dinosaurs are cool.</h2>

  <button class='change-text'>Change Text</button>

  <script>
  document.querySelector('.change-text').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('h2').innerText = 'I AM A DINOSAUR!!!';
  }); </script>
```

Any idea why? I've been told to link my javascript's at the top of the head, and that doesn't make this work either.

I'd love some help, thank you so much =)

Comment: The location matters, scripts are loading synchronously in order.

Comment: so i can't link a .js file in the <head> and expect all the code to work if i use querySelector on any element in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Because your script runs immediately, it must come *after* the HTML it is working with.  When the script comes before the elements, those elements don't exist and therefore -- the script crashes.

Scripts placed in the HEAD section usually wait for the `domDocumentReady` or the `load` event, either one meaning the page has loaded enough that all the elements exist and the script can safely run.  (in jQuery, this is also available through the `$(...)` function or `$(document).ready(...)`

Now days, it is common to put the scripts at the BOTTOM of the page, just before the closing `</body>` so that the rest of the page can load and render before scripts start to load.

Comment: Does an obvious dupe really need another duplicate answer?

Answer (score 0):

First example does not work because you try to add event to element which not exists in your html code yet. It's a good habit to place all of your scripts just before the end of `body` tag or use `onload` event.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it matters.
To make this work you can wrap your action in a function and call it on page load.
This will guarantee you that button has been rendered.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the code does not work becasue at the moment the browser executes your code, it does not know anything about any elements with class `change-text`. In your latter example, when the code is placed after this element, it is already known to the browser at the moment of script execution.

It's a good practice to load JS code at the very end of your body tag, when all the HTML has already been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

when you are trying to load an HTML you should to consider that the order is very important because the way that the file is rendered is from top to bottom.

What does it means?, lets divide your example in three parts.

First:

```
<h2>Dinosaurs are cool.</h2>
```

Seconds:

```
 <script>
 document.querySelector('.change-text').addEventListener('click', function () {
 document.querySelector('h2').innerText = 'I AM A DINOSAUR!!!';
 }); </script>
```

Third:

```
<button class='change-text'>Change Text</button>
```

The first thing that our browser loads is the first part. The browser don't know anything about the second or third part.

A few miliseconds after, our browser load the second part. Yes! now He (the browser) knows the existence of the first part, and if in our second piece of code wants to manipulate the first part of code, can do it.

A few miliseconds after this, the third piece of code is ready, and them all our html is loaded.

In you case, in your second code, you're trying to manipulate a html tag that the don't know where is it, and for these reason you have 2 options:

1. Locate your js at the bottom of your html document,
2. Wait until all the dom is ready, but... how you can do that:

   1. Using jQuery and the "ready" function (https://api.jquery.com/ready/)
   2. Using the onLoad function (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

Regards,
Idir

Answer (score -1):

this will not work as you are trying to call DOM element before loading it on the page.

```
<h2>Dinosaurs are cool.</h2>

  <script>
  document.querySelector('.change-text').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('h2').innerText = 'I AM A DINOSAUR!!!';
  }); </script>

  <button class='change-text'>Change Text</button>
```

You can use this to wait for all DOM elements:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

So you need to make sure that you have element on your page before calling that element.